Is pumping up sets right-differentiable?
Take a compact set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $X_r:=\{x+y\in\mathbb{R}^n:x\in X\land|y|<r\}$ for all $r>0$. I wonder if the function $V:r\mapsto\text{Vol}(X_r)$ has right and left derivatives. I have only been able to prove that it is Lipschitz continuous on finite intervals but not that it has any derivative. Not that I want those derivatives to exist everywhere, not just almost everywhere.
I believe that this is true because in case $X$ was convex the result comes from basic knowledge of mixed volumes. In general, the $n$-th root of $V(r)$ is not concave (which is true for convex $X$), take for example the union of a ball and a point. On the other hand, $V(r)$ itself is not convex, take for example an open disk without $Y_\varepsilon$ where $Y$ is a line contained in the interior of that disk. I have also been able to prove that $V(r)$ is the supremum of functions which do have right and left derivatives.
Methods that I used for my results are:

Choosing finitely many points from $X$ and then dividing the family of all balls of radius $r$ that are subsets of $X_r$ into finitely many families, one for each point we chose from $X$. We assign a ball to a point iff the distance between that point and the ball's center is less than $r/2$. We now represent $X_r$ as the finite union of unions of all balls in each family.
Choosing finitely many balls of radius $r$ that are subsets of $X_r$ such that their union approximates $X_r$. Now imagine $X$ was the set of the centers of these balls and prove the theorem for such $X$.

